# why creating docker container with custom user republishes derived images?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am reading [an article](https://blog.csanchez.org/2017/01/31/running-docker-containers-as-non-root/) on docker security about running docker processes as  non-root user.it states that:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
RUN useradd --create-home -s /bin/bash user
WORKDIR /home/user
USER user
```

> This is simple, but forces us to republish all these derived images,
>   creating a maintenance nightmare.

1) what does it mean by republishing derived images?
2) How is this a maintenance nightmare?
3) Isn't this a common practice as most examples on internet user similar method to run docker as non-root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say I have an application

```sh
FROM openjdk:8-jre
COPY myapp.jar /
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/myapp.jar"]
```

Now, I want to use your technique to have a common non-root user.  So I need to change this Dockerfile to

```sh
FROM my/openjdk:8-jre # <-- change the base image name
USER root             # <-- change back to root for file installation
COPY myapp.jar ./
USER user             # <-- use non-root user at runtime
CMD ["java", "-jar", "./myapp.jar"]
```

Further, suppose there's a Java security issue and I need to update everything to a newer JRE.  If I'm using the standard OpenJDK image, I just need to make sure I've `docker pull`ed a newer image and then rebuild my application image.  But if I'm using your custom intermediate image, I need to rebuild that image first, then rebuild the application.  This is where the maintenance burden comes in.

In my Docker images I tend to just `RUN adduser` and specify the `USER` in the image itself.  (They don't need a home directory or any particular shell, and they definitely should not have a host-dependent user ID.)  If you broadly think of a Dockerfile as having three "parts" – setting up OS-level dependencies, installing the application, and defining runtime parameters – I generally put this in the first part.

```sh
FROM openjdk:8-jre  # <-- standard Docker Hub image
RUN adduser user    # <-- add the user as a setup step
WORKDIR /app
COPY myapp.jar .    # <-- install files at root
USER user           # <-- set the default runtime user
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/myapp.jar"]
```

(Say your application has a security issue.  If you've installed files as root and are running the application as non-root, then the attacker can't overwrite the installed application inside the container.)

Comment: thanks for the explanation but i am still not clear. how is you final dockerfile different from my example above other than i am creating a home directory and a shell for the `user`.  why would i need to write
` FROM my/openjdk:8-jre`?

Comment: In my final Dockerfile, I’m actually installing the application.  To use the Dockerfile from the question (that only adds a non-root user) you need to modify your Dockerfile that installs the application to be based on it (my middle example), and if the JRE updates, you need to rebuild _both_ images, in order.